# Setting the Navigation Bar to cover the Status bar in Modal Segues

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

This could be a stupid question but i couldn't figure it out.
When i create a Push Segue it automatically should give me this if has a nav controller
[image]

while when i create a Modal Segue i need to set a navigationBar from the palette and looks like this
[image]

How can i make a custom navBar dragged from the palette to look like the first one?
I need this because i set the Status Bar text to white in order to be in contrast with the navigation bar color, but in this was the status bar is invisible, being white on the white background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a property to the offset and height constraints.  Then in the viewWillAppear method, set the constraints value to be -20 and 64 respectively

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear];
    [self.myNavBarTopConstraint setConstant:-20];
    [self.myNavBarHeightConstraint setConstant:64];
}
```

Comment: Already tried but the problem is that it just moves the navBar. The first pic has a navBar bigger than the second, the way should be to increase it's height.

Comment: What if you push onto a navigation controller, rather than just a view with a nag bar added?

Comment: You could also add a height constraint and change it on view did load to be 64; I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: i'll try this, but problem is when i have to do a modalSegue, in this case i have a smaller navBar

Comment: how can i acces the constraint you said?

Comment: You should have set them up in storyboard.  If you haven't then do. Once they are created, just select the constraint you want to add a property to and control drag to the top of view controller file to add it as a property.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45843/discussion-between-jbryson-and-obiwankenerd)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are creating your own title bar.. what you should do.. instead of presenting modally the destination view controller... present modally a navigationcontroller.. that has the destination view controller set as root view controller.

hope you can understand what tried to say =P!

GL HF

[hope this helps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkA1m.png)

Comment: You mean to "embed in" a nav controller to any modalSegueDestinationController right? is it good practice?

Comment: not really sure if a good practice.. but it is the best way I found to solve the problem... and it is just as easy as making a little modification to the storyboard.

Comment: I tried to solve it by code.. supporting iOS 6 and 7, but making the color match between the status bar and the navigation bar is just a pain the ass.